# I get error when i try to add value to defaultdict(str)

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying  to add value:'a[1]+ " "+a[2]' to key:'a[0]' in defaultdict(str).i am getting following error when i try to run my code:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add'

```
files_summary = defaultdict(str)

for line in file:
     a = line.split()
     files_summary[a[0]].add(a[1]+ " "+a[2])

for i in files_summary.items():
     print(i)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why do you expect the resultant value of the expression `files_summary[a[0]]` to have an `.add` method? It is unclear what you expect.

Comment: i want to add 'a[1]+ " "+a[2]' as a value to defaultdict(str). append dosent work, nor does add

Comment: what do you imagine `.add` is supposed to do?? Why did you write that?

Comment: add value to key a[o]

Comment: i want to add value 'a[1]+ " "+a[2]' to key 'a[0]' in defaultdict(str)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fix for the AttributeError

Strings support a "+=" operation rather than an *add()* method:

```
files_summary = defaultdict(str)

for line in file:
     a = line.split()
     files_summary[a[0]] += a[1]+ " " + a[2]

for i in files_summary.items():
     print(i)
```

### Better way with "join"

That said, the algorithmically better way to accumulate strings is to build-up a list and then [*str.join()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them at the end.

```
files_summary = defaultdict(list)

for line in file:
     a = line.split()
     files_summary[a[0]].append(a[1]+ " " + a[2])

for key, strings in files_summary.items():
     print(key, ''.join(strings))
```